# How to GET a read-only vs editable resource in REST style?

Tags: url, rest

I'm fairly familiar with REST principles, and have read the relevant dissertation, Wikipedia entry, a bunch of blog posts and StackOverflow questions on the subject, but still haven't found a straightforward answer to a common case:

I need to request a resource to display. Depending on the resource's state, I need to render either a read-only or an editable representation. In both cases, I need to GET the resource. How do I construct a URL to get the read-only or editable version?

If my user follows a link to `GET /resource/<id>`, that should suffice to indicate to me that s/he needs the read-only representation. But if I need to server up an editable form, what does that URL look like? `GET /resource/<id>/edit` is obvious, but it contains a verb in the URL. Changing that to `GET /resource/<id>/editable` solves that problem, but at a seemingly superficial level. Is that all there is to it -- change verbs to adjectives?

If instead I use POST to retrieve the editable version, then how do I distinguish between the POST that initially retrieves it, vs the POST that saves it? My (weak) excuse for using POST would be that retrieving an editable version would cause a change of state on the server: locking the resource. But that only holds if my requirements are to implement such a lock, which is not always the case. PUT fails for the same reason, plus PUT is not enabled by default on the Web servers I'm running, so there are practical reasons not to use it (and DELETE).

Note that even in the editable state, I haven't made any changes yet; presumably when I submit the resource to the Web server again, I'd POST it. But to get something that I can later POST, the server has to *first* serve up a particular representation.

I guess another approach would be to have separate resources at the collection level:
`GET /read-only/resource/<id>` and `GET /editable/resource/<id>` or `GET /resource/read-only/<id>` and `GET /resource/editable/<id>` ... but that looks pretty ugly to me.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) It is perfectly valid to have two distinct resources, one for viewing and one for editing some domain concept.  Just be aware that because they are two different URIs from REST's perspective they are two different resources.  Too often people conflate resource with domain object.  That's why they end up being stuck only doing CRUD.

2) Don't get too hung up on the name of the resource. The important thing is that you realize that what the URI points to is a "thing", "a resource". If that's more obvious to you with `editable` instead of `edit` then use that.  Having a verb in your URL doesn't make your application wrong, it just makes it a bit less readable to the human developer.  Using a verb in the URL to try and redefine the semantics of the HTTP method, now that's a violation of the uniform interface constraint.

Comment: re #2, I'm pretty disciplined about that; I channel all state-changing requests thru POST and all read requests thru GET. It's not practical for me to use PUT or DELETE. Good point about the difference betw. a resource and domain obj. I tend to think of the resource as a request for the object in a particular state.

Answer (score 3):

In REST, editing an existing resource is accomplished by a client GET-ing a representation of that resource, making changes to the representation, and then doing a PUT of the new representation back to the server.

So to just *read* a resource your REST client program would do a:

```
GET http://www.example.com/SomeResource
```

And to *edit* that resource:

```
GET http://www.example.com/SomeResource
... edit it ...
PUT http://www.example.com/SomeResource
```

Normally simultaneous updates are handled by letting the last PUT arriving at the server overwrite the earlier ones, on the assumption that it represents a newer state.  But in your case you want to guard against this.

Carefully consider @Jason's suggestion to maintain an optional parallel lock resource for each main resource.  Your client would first create the lock, do the edit, then delete the lock.  Your system would need to release a lock automatically if the user making the lock subsequently never saves any changes.  This would look like:

```
GET http://www.example.com/SomeResource     
... user presses an edit button ...
PUT http://www.example.com/SomeResource/lock    
... user edits the resource's representation ...
PUT http://www.example.com/SomeResource
DELETE http://www.example.com/SomeResource/lock
```

You'd need to do some appropriate error handling if the user is trying to edit a resource that's locked by someone else.

It sounds like you feel you're constrained by the current limitations of HTML.  If you use a server-side REST framework like Restlet (for Java), it supports the notion of "overloaded POST", where you can use POST but tack on a query string argument like method=PUT or method=DELETE.  If you're writing your own server-side components they can use this trick too.

There are tricks you can play at the HTML level too.  For instance your page can have a read-only part that's initially displayed, *and* an input form that's initially not shown.  When the user presses the edit button, your JavaScript hides the read-only part and shows the input form.

Be sure to read Richardson and Ruby's Restful Web Services (O'Reilly) too.  It's extremely helpful.

Comment: My problem is not the POST that saves the edits; that's perfectly clear. It's on the GET. The server knows if the resource is editable, since the server has stored the state of that resource. I guess I could 'play HTML tricks', but that seems to abuse the architecture. Instead, I want to request an editable representation of the resource. Your first GET example skips that. If I GET the resource, and then click an Edit button, what's the URL that button requests from the server? If it's all on the browser in JavaScript, that imposes all kinds of constraints and simply bails on the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think returning a form or just values is up to a REST server, but the responsibility of the client. Whether a resource is *editable* is a property of the resource, and not something defined by the URL.

In other words: The URL for getting the resource is `GET /resource/<id>`. This has a property editable. If a user wants a form it can retrieve the resource from the same URL and populate the form. The client can than PUT/POST changes.

Comment: Where's the 'editable' property stored, and how do I get at it? I don';t expect it to be _defined_ by the URL, but I do expect it to be _specified_ in the URL. Since my server is serving the resource, it seems to me it's absolutely the server's responsibility to serve the appropriate representation, based on the URL I requested. And a form vs. a bunch of DIVs is exactly a difference in representation of the same abstract resource, no?

Comment: You infer it from the resource's state, that's what you said yourself:  "Depending on the resource's state, I need to render either a read-only or an editable representation". However, maybe you mean you want to determine it by means of the URL. In which case we're back at the starting point. But then you are probably looking at the problem in the wrong way. Displaying different representations of the same resource is NOT RESTful: "Servers are not concerned with the user interface".

Comment: just because it's editable doesn't mean I want to edit it, or that the current user has permissions to edit it. I want the collection page to render URLs for the available states. I'll display Read and Edit links as appropriate based on authorization, etc., but I need the URLs; that's the discoverability part of REST. I don't grok the last bit; my UI layer is concerned with the UI, but I still need to serve a different representation based on state. The URL represents the state. REST seems very much about displaying different representations for the same resource.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I construct a URL to get the read-only or editable version?

There's an underlying problem here, which is that you are constructing URLs in the first place - appending IDs to hard-coded URLs is not REST.  [Roy Fielding has written about this very mistake](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven).  Whichever document prompts you to edit the resource should contain the URI to the editable variant of that resource.  You follow that URI, whether that's `/resource/editable` or `/editable/resource` is outside the scope of REST.

Comment: Yes, and that's exactly what will happen. I'll get to the individual resource from a list of the collection of such resources, and that list will hyperlink to each individual resource with a link based on and expressing the state of the target resource. So, the collection will have links like `GET /resources/resource/23` and `GET /resources/resource/24/edit`. It's just that everything I read sez that having a verb (e.g. 'edit') in the URL is a bad smell. Should I just get over it?

Comment: Fielding has a blog?! +11111111

Comment: Ah, right, gotcha.  I think it's valuable to keep that as a rule of thumb, but it's by no means a black and white issue.  To me, your approach isn't a problem - calling it "edit" in the first place is a misnomer, as what is actually happening is that you are retrieving an editable version of the resource, not actually performing the edit (that happens in the client, not as part of the protocol).

Comment: @Jim, You're right about the misnomer -- maybe I'm back to an 'editable' adjective for the initial retrieval. When I want to commit the edit, I POST the resource; if I decide not to edit it, I simply navigate away (and now I have to figure out how to quickly release the lock I set...)

Comment: Not sure if it's an option for you, but WebDAV defines HTTP methods for locking.

Comment: @Val Don't get too hung up on the name. The important thing is that you realize that what the URI points to is a "thing", "a resource".  If that's more obvious to you with `editable` then use that.

Comment: @Darrel, thanks, I think that's the conclusion I'm coming to. If you make that an answer I'm about ready to accept it and move on with life ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> If instead I use POST to retrieve the editable version, then how do I distinguish between the POST that initially retrieves it, vs the POST that saves it?

You perform a GET (not a POST) to read the resource, and POST (or PUT) to write the resource.

If you want to create a lock on the resource in question, use POST to write to the resource (or the resource's container, with the resource ID encoded in the body of the POST), and have the server create a lock *as a new resource*, and return an ID of that resource as the response to the POST. (with authentication issues beyond the scope of your question or this answer)

Then to unlock the lock, either use a DELETE on the lock resource, or POST to the lock's container.

Comment: Yes, I know, and that's the crux of my problem. I gave the PUT and POST examples of approaches I *don't think will work*, even if I can find marginally-semantic reasons for them. So, back to GET. How do I distinguish between and editable and non-editable representation?

Comment: why would they be any different? (in the context of a GET)

Comment: They'd be different because one needs to be editable. That means I need to render a form. I need to know if I render the requested resource in a form or not. How do I know how to render the resource?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your question could be "how to identify the readonly representation that return with GET action in PUT action?". You could do this:

```
<Root>
<readonly>
<p1><p1>
...
<readonly>
<others>
...
<others>
<Root>
```

After parsing the request XML from PUT you can ignore the readonly part and process others. In Response, return 200 status and leave a message saying the part in readonly is ignored. 
Is it your expected?